# "time span" or "time spans" or "the time span"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

What I want to say is: the longer time duration between the first and second exam, the less useful they become. I am not sure which of the following is correct:

> the longer the time spans between the first and second exam, the less
> useful they become.

Or,

> the longer time span between the first and second exam, the less
> useful they become.

Or,

> the longer time spans between the first and second exam, the less
> useful they become.

EDIT:
According to the first comment, I add this suggestion:

> the longer the time span between the first and second exam, the less the
> useful they become.

Comment: Pattern: The + comparative adjective + the noun, the + comparative adjective.+ the noun. or verb.

Comment: The time between the first and second exams is a single time span. And "time span" is a noun. You wouldn't use "spans" as a verb in that sense.

Comment: @Lambie Can you check my edit. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

> **the longer the time span** between the first and second exam, the less useful they become.

There is only one time span. The plural form "time span**s**" is not correct.

In "the longer the time spans", "spans" could be a verb, but it's still incorrect, because time doesn't span.

The article before "time span" is important. Otherwise, "the longer time span" is a noun phrase, which refers to one particular time span.

```
"The bigger the bread loaf, the greater the price."  
            ^^^

"The bigger bread loaf is too expensive. I will buy the smaller one."
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 refers to a specific bread loaf
```